# ocultar y mostrar menu con React.js

Tags: javascript, web, reactjs

hola estoy pasando mi pagina a react.js pero no entiendo como poder abrir mi menu y que se cierre, en mi pagina ocupo jquey e igual con el logo del menu la X y la hamburguesa que cambien cuando se habre el menu, la verdad no tengo ningun codigo de javascript por que me he quedado atorado viendo ejemplos y no entiendo

```
<nav role="navigation" className="nav-menu-2 w-nav-menu">
        <div>
          <a href="../index.html" className="nav-link-6 _2 w-nav-link">INICIO</a>
          <a href="tecnologias.html" className="nav-link-6 _1 w-nav-link">TECNOLOGÍAS</a>
          <a href="../Vision/VISION.html" className="nav-link-5 w-nav-link">VISION</a>
          <a href className="nav-link-5 _2 w-nav-link">CASOS DE USO </a>
          <a href="../Nosotros/Nosotros.html" className="nav-link-3 w-nav-link">NOSOTROS </a>
          <a href className="nav-link-6 w-nav-link">DEMO </a>
          <a href="https://medium.com/@spotcloudio" target="_blank" style={{color: '#fff', cursor: 'pointer'}} className="nav-link-6 w-nav-link">BLOG</a>
        </div>
        <div className="redes">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/spotcloud/" className="li" target="_blank"><img src="../images/027-linkedin%20(1).svg" alt /></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SpotCloud.io/" className="fb" target="_blank"><img src="../images/036-facebook.svg" alt /></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spotcloud.io/?hl=es-la" className="in" target="_blank"><img src="../images/4-layers.svg" alt /></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div className="menu-button-2 a.cp_btns1 w-nav-button" data-ix="navbar"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b71b8c59c22cb48ab086d4a/5b736bcf05c5995c9ece2124_11-layers.svg" className="img-i" /><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b71b8c59c22cb48ab086d4a/5b736c0003163dfe7a60c742_3-layers.svg" className="image-29 img-x" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo a que hamburguesa y que X te refieres. El pasar una página ya construida a react no es algo trivial. Como ejemplo, el uso de jQuery es desaconsejado ya que los cambios en el DOM son controlados por react y no otras librerías. Te aconsejo que si usas alguna librería en particular, como bootstrap, material design, etc, busques sus versiones para react. Si no te sirve lo que te digo, reformula tu pregunta para [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), porque no muestras como haces la animación ni que librería usas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas trabajando con React, trabajamos con componentes, y lo mejor seria que el menu de hamburguesa sea un componente que llamas desde tu aplicacion principal.

Para mostrar y cerrar el menu, podes setear en el estado de la aplicacion principal un booleano que indique si el componente es visible o no, y de acuerdo a eso con if ternarios lo mostras o no.

Para mostrarlo seteas en el evento click del icono de hamburguesa que sea visible, y para cerrarlo, haces una funcion en la aplicacion principal que setea el booleano a no visible. Esta funcion se la pasas como propiedad a el componente del menu.

Mas o menos el codigo seria asi:

Aplicacion principal:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  // aqui importas el componente, poniendo el path donde estaria ubicado.
  import BurguerMenu from './tupath.js'

  class Main extends Component {

    state ={
      BurguerMenuVisible: false
    }

    openBurguerMenu = () => {
      this.setState({BurguerMenuVisible: true})
    }

    closeBurguerMenu = () => {
      this.setState({BurguerMenuVisible: false})
    }

    render() {
      return(
        //Aqui tendras los componentes de tu aplicacion. Entre esos el menu al que le 
        //pasas la funcion cerrar como propiedad
       { this.state.burguerMenuVisible &&            
        <BurguerMenu clickCerrar = {this.closeBurguerMenu} />
       }
        //tambien tendras tu boton hamburguesa que el el OnClick le pasas la funcion de abrir
        //suponiendo que es un boton...
        <button type = "button" onClick = {this.openBurguerMenu}></button>
      )
    }
  }
```

el componente de menu hamburguesa puede ser un componente funcional ya que no necesitaras tener estados ni nada mas que renderear el menu. A tu codigo solo le agregas el Onclick en el boton X y le pasas la funcion de cerrar:

```
import React from 'react';

function BurguerMenu(props) {

return(  
<nav role="navigation" className="nav-menu-2 w-nav-menu">
        <div>
          <a href="../index.html" className="nav-link-6 _2 w-nav-link">INICIO</a>
          <a href="tecnologias.html" className="nav-link-6 _1 w-nav-link">TECNOLOGÍAS</a>
          <a href="../Vision/VISION.html" className="nav-link-5 w-nav-link">VISION</a>
          <a href className="nav-link-5 _2 w-nav-link">CASOS DE USO </a>
          <a href="../Nosotros/Nosotros.html" className="nav-link-3 w-nav-link">NOSOTROS </a>
          <a href className="nav-link-6 w-nav-link">DEMO </a>
          <a href="https://medium.com/@spotcloudio" target="_blank" style={{color: '#fff', cursor: 'pointer'}} className="nav-link-6 w-nav-link">BLOG</a>
        </div>
        <div className="redes">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/spotcloud/" className="li" target="_blank"><img src="../images/027-linkedin%20(1).svg" alt /></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SpotCloud.io/" className="fb" target="_blank"><img src="../images/036-facebook.svg" alt /></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spotcloud.io/?hl=es-la" className="in" target="_blank"><img src="../images/4-layers.svg" alt /></a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div onClick = {props.clickCerrar} className="menu-button-2 a.cp_btns1 w-nav-button" data-ix="navbar"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b71b8c59c22cb48ab086d4a/5b736bcf05c5995c9ece2124_11-layers.svg" className="img-i" /><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5b71b8c59c22cb48ab086d4a/5b736c0003163dfe7a60c742_3-layers.svg" className="image-29 img-x" /></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BurguerMenu
```